# iOS FBAudienceNetwork Error codes consts

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-audience-network

In android when I get error I get an com.facebook.ads.AdError class.
For that i can check which kind of error as occurred (like NETWORK_ERROR_CODE,NO_FILL_ERROR_CODE,...)

In iOS i am getting a general NSError object in case of error, for example:

`- (void)adView:(FBAdView *)adView didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;`

how can I check which kind of error occurred in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are no error domains or constants in FBAudienceNetwork iOS SDK.**

`com.facebook.ads.AdError.NO_FILL_ERROR_CODE` is a local error code for FB SDK (android). It is not necessary that you can find those codes in iOS.

To see detail of error just log your error like so:

```
NSLog(@"Error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
```

Error Codes available in Facebook SDK can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/error-reference) (Facebook Ads).

I'll suggest you to find error domain first. iOS usage Domains and Codes for error identification. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001704-SW8)

`NSURLErrorDomain` codes are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes).

Comment: I want to handle the error
do something like in android 
if (error.getErrorCode() == com.facebook.ads.AdError.NO_FILL_ERROR_CODE){...}

Comment: but where are the Audience network error codes? (like the NO_FILL)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes   all available error codes for URL Domain.

Comment: com.facebook.ads.AdError.NO_FILL_ERROR_CODE is a local error code for FB SDK (android). It is not necessary that you can find those codes in iOS.

Comment: BTW facebook sdk has a class which handle error for you. read here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKErrorRecoveryAttempting/

Comment: thanks for your time. write as an answer the comment about NO_FILL_ERROR_CODE is local error code so i mark it as answered

Comment: you can still manage your errors. fb SDKs usage a private library which format all error (as fb sdk identify) into a NSError object. So until any help you can hit and try with these errors. As i studied all these sdks, most errors are network or auth based and sdk have constant for those.